# How do I convert these Sub procedures to work on two worksheets?

Tags: vba, excel

I am working with a workbook version of a character sheet for the tabletop game MERP. It was originally written (by someone else) about fifteen years ago, so much of it was not optimized for modern use, and I have been overhauling it. I am fine with the formulas, and I get basic programming concepts, but I am not well versed in Virtual Basic.

As part of the overhaul, I have been splitting the original pages into a print and calculating version of each, as the relevant information changes significantly. One page uses a macro to hide the rows that have not had values changed, and another to show all rows. I am trying to modify the macro so that it affects two pages instead of one, but I am apparently not understanding the structure needed.

How do I modify this so that it performs the same functions on both the "Skills" sheet and the "Print Skills" sheet? I can include the reference column on "Print Skills" if I need to, but I would prefer that it just match what is done on "Skills", without a second check. The relevant data is the same on both sheets.

Here is the original code:

```
' HideSkills Macro
'   This macro hides any line on the Skills sheet that doesn't
'   have a 1 in the Display column.

 Sub HideSkills()
    SkillsHidden = True
    Sheets("Skills").Select
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    Computation_Off
    For Each rw In Range("SkillsList").Rows
        If ActiveSheet.Cells(rw.Row, 21) = 0 Then
            Rows(rw.Row).Select
            Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next rw
    ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
    Computation_On
End Sub

' ShowSkills Macro
'   This macro shows all lines on the Skills sheet.

Sub ShowSkills()
    SkillsHidden = False
    Sheets("Skills").Select
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    Range("SkillsList").Rows.Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
    ActiveSheet.Cells(4, 2).Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one way to optimize the methods, and allow them to act on multiple sheets

```
Option Explicit

' This Sub hides any line on the sheet that doesn't have a 1 in the Display column.
Public Sub HideSkills(ByRef ws As Worksheet, Optional ByVal colID As Long = 21)
    SkillsHidden = True
    Computation_Off
    With ws
       .Unprotect
       If .UsedRange.Rows.Count > 1 Then .UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=colID, Criteria1:="1"
       .Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
    End With
    Computation_On
End Sub


' This Sub shows all lines on the sheet
Public Sub ShowSkills(ByRef ws As Worksheet)
    SkillsHidden = False
    With ws
        .Unprotect
        .UsedRange.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        If Not .AutoFilter Is Nothing Then .UsedRange.AutoFilter
        .Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
        .Activate
        .Cells(4, 2).Activate
    End With
End Sub
```

---

To call the Subs for 2 different sheets:

```
Public Sub testSheets()
    HideSkills ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Skills"), 21
    HideSkills ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Print Skills")

    ShowSkills ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Skills")
    ShowSkills ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Print Skills")
End Sub
```

Comment: Than you for this answer. Unfortunately, I have been pulled away to other projects, and haven't had a chance to test it yet.  I haven't forgotten!